# Convert MySQL to a new system?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an old MySQL table structure that I want to upgrade to a new one, I'll explain the structures below.

Its for a permission system, and the table represents what rank id's get what permission id's

Table [Old]:
`permission_id` the id of the permission given
`rank` the rank id that gets the permission

Now, for the old table system, it uses an extra call to `permissions` table to find the name of the permission linked with `permission_id`, in my new system I just store permission rights by permission's name not the permissions id.

Table [New]:
`permission_name` the name of the permission given
`allowed_ranks` a string of rank ids, seperated by `,`

How would I convert all the records to 1 simple record for all permissions, but convert the `rank` column to the new `allowed_ranks` with a seperator of ,?

Comment: _"a string of rank ids, seperated by ,"_ Don't do that. See [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Comment: Also, it's generally not great practice to replace easily indexed, searched, joined, etc... integer id references with much more expensive string ones. Basically, it sounds like your "upgrade project" is the exact opposite of an upgrade.

Comment: I agree with the other comments: This will not improve your system. If you want to get rid of a separate query to retrieve the permission's name, just JOIN the table to the query that retrieves the permission. This will still be much faster than using strings.

Answer (score 1):

Do not convert to the new system if you have any choice.
You can avoid *"an extra call to permissions"* by just joining the tables.

```
SELECT * 
FROM old_table AS t 
INNER JOIN permissions AS p ON t.permission_id = p.permission_id 
WHERE t.rank = ?
;
```

If you need to **display** the information in the new table format, just use this query:

```
SELECT p.permission_name, GROUP_CONCAT(t.rank) AS allowed_ranks
FROM old_table AS t 
INNER JOIN permissions AS p ON t.permission_id = p.permission_id 
GROUP BY p.permission_name
;
```

*Note: you could use the second query to populate the new table, but it is pretty much guaranteed you will quickly regret moving to it; at least, once you have to find all permissions associated with a specific rank.*